# Node, express and Request on placeholder displaying lots on \n

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, express, request

I am using Node and Express with request.js to get data from json placeholder.

Here is the code:

```
...
import request from 'request';

const app = express();

app.get('/users', (req, res) => {
    request('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users', (error, response, body) => {
        res.json(body)
    });
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
 console.log("Server running on port 3000");
});
```

The problem is I'm getting lots of \n for example:

```
"[\n  {\n    \"id\": 1,\n    \"name\": \"Leanne Graham\",\n    \"username\": \"Bret\",\n   etc
```

How can I get just clean json formatted without the extras?

Comment: Is there a Github repo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`res.json()` calls `JSON.stringify()` which turns the object into a `string`. Use `res.send()` to send the JSON.

Answer (score 1):

Just add the `json` option to parse the placeholder's response before send it to the client:

```
app.get('/users', (req, res) => {
    request({
      url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users'
      json: true // this option parses the response's body as JSON
    }, (error, response, body) => {
        res.json(body)
    });
});
```